# How to notify a user to enter a value into a cell left blank if they have entered value's into another cell

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vba

[Excel Worksheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LsABP.png)
[image]

This is an example of a spreadsheet that I'm using to plan run times for service workers. `C9` & `C10` to `J9` & `J10` are times that are input on the day, the then technician needs to plan the run for the day, `B11` is the time to travel from the last site back to the branch.

***My question is:***
When values have been entered into the `C9:J9` & `C10:J10` range, I want Excel to prompt the technician to remember to add in the time for B11 if possible via a error message.

**About the Spreadsheet:** The technician will add the times in `C9:J9` & `C10:J10` in minute form, and this gets converted to Time in `B9` and `B10`. They are then summed together and up to 7 hours is put into `D11` and any excess hours is then put into F11.

Comment: The best would be VBA macro, check whether cells are not empty & display prompt message,, if you are comfortable with VBA then confirm through comments,, also [Edit] you post & add Tag `VBA`.

Comment: I'm comfortable with VBA.

Comment: You said "via an error message". Using error usually means that the action is blocked until the blocking condition is remedied (in this case, D11 being blank?). Will you accept if the technician should enter the value in D11, before putting anything on C9:J9 and C10:J10 ?

Comment: Or you mean more like a "warning" or "reminder" pop-up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Use this VBA subroutine as Standard module.*

**N.B.**

- Double click the Worksheet's name in the VBA's Project Explorer, and *Copy* & *Paste* this code.

---

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
 If Not (Application.Intersect(Range("C9:J10"), Target) Is Nothing) Then

  MsgBox "Cell " & Target.Address & " has filled/altered, now enter data into B11.", vbInformation, "Prompting you,,"

  Range("B11").Select
  End If
End Sub
```

- As soon technician start filling/altering data into range `C9:J10`,, macro pop message along with the Cell been filled,, to fil the `B11`.

*You may adjust cell references in this code as needed.*

Comment: That doesn't belong in a standard public module code sheet. It belongs in that particular worksheet's private code sheet accessed easily by double-clicking the worksheet's name in the VBA's Project Manager.

Comment: @Jeeped,, thanks for the observation,, technical key word `standard public module code with sheet` is missing, and the reason is that OP is well versed with VBA and I'm sure he could mange it,, and above all it's even working as Private module,, since I've tested it before post,,,,but for the others I'll edit the post soon.

Comment: Thank you Rajesh, i'm currently unable to upvote

Comment: Glad to help you @JarnDechert,, keep asking ☺

Comment: @JarnDechert,, either [Edit] you post & add Caveat that you need something new or please post a New Question and if you feel prompt me through comments to answer,, since post any CODE or longer Formula as comments is not possible as well as against the norms of the community also.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to using macros is to place a formula like this wherever you’d like the message to show up:

```
=If(COUNTA(C9:J10)>1,”Please add the time”,””)
```

This assumes C9:J10 is blank until someone starts entering information.

Comment: This is a decent alternative.